# How can I reduce loading time for a website with many images?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loading

I built my photography website with angularjs, but loading time is relatively slow.

What can I do to improve loading time other than reducing the image file size?
Or, at least speed up the perception of loading time?

Link to my website is www.jbkphotographs.com

Comment: There are rather many different strategies for optimizing load times making this question a bit broad for Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks. To be honest, I am a bit lost on where to begin.

Comment: @EvanCarslake this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: Maybe this question could go to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I did a fresh load of your web page with Chrome's Network tab open, and copied the image here:

[image]

It shows that loading your Javascript files is taking up most of the time.  angular.js, jquery-2.1.3.js and ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js all took over one second to load.

If you could compress them, that should save some time.  Another trick is to use the public CDNs instead of your own server, that's why they're there (like the Google Fonts):

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-bootstrap

http://cdnjs.com/libraries/masonry

Comment: notice how you can only grab 6 urls from your site at once, which is why you have so many blocks of six. using cdns would free up those limited own-site pipelines to allow custom code to hit sooner. a cdn angular.js copy in particular  would likely make a huge impact.